# Help identify this white and medium grey ship section

Tags: set-identification

Can you help identify this ship section from a box of LEGO parts we have now?  It looks like it was in an epic battle.

[image: Section of the ship]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [Engine 3X3X6](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4142999) in white, this is from [7166-1: Imperial Shuttle](https://brickset.com/sets/7166-1/Imperial-Shuttle)

[image]

Or as Syberion mentioned it can also be 
[7264-1: Imperial Inspection](https://brickset.com/sets/7264-1/Imperial-Inspection)

[image]

Which has almost the same build. The only difference I could find is the color of the 6 x 12 plates on the bottom of the build.

- 7166: [Dark Gray Plate 6 x 12](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3028&colorID=10&in=A)
- 7264: [Dark Bluish Gray Plate 6 x 12](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3028&colorID=85&in=A)

Based on the photo, I think its Dark Bluish Gary so it's 7264.

If you still have the minifigs for this set they will also tell you which set it is, as 7166 had the yellow faced figures and 7264 had the flesh tone figures.

Comment: It could also be from 7264-1: Imperial Inspection
they have the same build

Comment: Indeed I stopped looking when I found the first one at brickset.